# how to customize joomla db sql error messages and how to prevent duplicate entries

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

my showtime table contains following fields,

**id, name, showtime** where **id** is a int type auto-increment field(pK). **showtime**  time type *unique* field .

when I try to add a showtime(duplicate value) to showtime field($row->store()) it shows the following joomla error message.(I used **$row->getError()** method)

```
    TableShowTime: :store failed
    Duplicate entry '10:30:00' for key 'showtime' SQL=INSERT INTO `jos_myextension_showtime` (`id`,`name`) VALUES ('0','evening')
```

I want to know is there any way to show only the db error message **without showing sql query**.
I have an idea to check the duplicate values using a query before insert, is it a good practice? Plz Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that if you don't want to display the query, then you shouldn't show the other part of the error message neither (don't tell the user you're trying to insert a duplicate key). A simple fix to this might be something like this:

```
if ( $row>getError() ) {
   echo "Could not store [...]";
}
```

If this is a custom component, you could also modify your table class to customize these error message, or even show distinct error messages depending on the error number.

I hope it helped!

Comment: thank you for your help. I also want to know are there any method to check the value(showtime) is already in table. I can do it using a simple select query. but is there any better method exist in Joomla?

Comment: I think a simple query is ok. Maybe there are other methods to do it, like trying to load a row based on the showtime value and return an error using info from that row if it's not empty, but a simple query is ok.